# xmpp openfire connection manager not working

Tags: windows-7, xmpp, openfire, concurrency

I have downloaded the connection manager [here](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/connection_manager.jsp) .In windows I have extracted it to program files in C drive and edit the conf/manager.xml to set domain and password. I also enabled connection manager in openfire management console.

Now If I run bin/cmanager.bat Nothing is happening. Connection Manager is not working. what is the issue? how to resolve it?

Comment: Showing any errors when you execute the bin/cmanager.bat?

Comment: command prompt window opens and closes in a flash. Also there are no error at connection_manager/logs